# Java Regex Alphabet Followed By Number

Tags: java, regex

I am getting file names as string as follows:

```
file_g001  
file_g222  
g_file_z999
```

I would like to return files that contains "g_x" where x is any number (as string). Note that the last file should not appear as the g_ is followed by an alphabet and not a number like the first 2.

I tried: `file.contains("_g[0-9]*$")` but this didn't work.

Expected results:

```
file_g001  
file_g222
```

Comment: there's a .png extension

Comment: It seems you are not looking for g_x, but for _gx, which means the third file won't be returned anyway

Comment: @TwoStarII use `file.matches(".*_g[0-9]*$")` or `file.matches(".*_g[0-9]*\\.png$")`...

Comment: brilliant- it works!
@brso05 post as answer and i'll accept

Comment: @TwoStarII go ahead and accept Arnaud Claudel's answer, it is essentially saying the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the method `contains` of String ?
If so, it does not work with regular expression.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

Consider using the method `matches`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is also fine, we'd just slightly improve that to:

```
^.*_g[0-9]+$
```

or

```
^.*_g\d+$
```

and it would likely work.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/WK9Zvv/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

---

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^.*_g[0-9]+$";
final String string = "file_g001\n"
     + "file_g222\n"
     + "file_some_other_words_g222\n"
     + "file_g\n"
     + "g_file_z999";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```